# Create unknown in advance Vue instances count

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In the question [Are multiple Vuejs instances possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47773253/4818123), below solution has been suggested:

```
new Vue({
 el: '#app1',
 data () {
   return {
     message: 'Hello'
   }
 },
})

new Vue({
 el: '#app2',
 data () {
   return {
     message: 'Helloa'
   }
 }
})
```

```html
<div id="app1">
  {{ message }}
</div>

<div id="app2">
  {{ message }}
</div>
```

Well, it works for two instances, but what if we does not know in advance, how many `<div id="appN">` will be? Also, it may not has id.

```html
<!-- we don't know in advance, how many it will be -->
<div class="target">
  {{ message }}
</div>

<div class="target">
  {{ message }}
</div>
```

Is Vue's flexibility ends here?

Comment: No, That's a single page configuration. If you want this to multiple pages then I suggest you to go for `component` based app. Get yourself started: https://cli.vuejs.org/

Comment: @SatyamPathak, thank you for the comment. Please, give me more concrete link. No search results for 'component based' in this documentation.

Comment: See, when you want to have multipage `vue` application. You need to set up the environment . The above link is for `vue cli` it will help you create such env. You can then create your multiple instances as `components`