# Starting with vue.js, problems with #app, # app1

Tags: vue.js

My question is, is it possible to put several id in the 'el:'?like

```
var app1 = new Vue({
    el: '#app, #app1',
    data: {
       
    }, // --- End of data --- //

}) // --- End of app1 --- //

// EOF
```

Comment: You can have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47773253/are-multiple-vuejs-instances-possible

Comment: Just create separate instances; it'll be easier to maintain the separation between components also this way.